# Gallery transitions become sluggish after a few prev/next clicks

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/kdpk7yu0/

If you click the next arrow a few times then the back arrows a few times the slide transitions become sluggish.

This is the first gallery I've built which has been cobbled together from various answers to get the following features:

- Allow multiple galleries on the page
- Toggle full screen mode
- Crop/scale images from their center
- When gallery is a child of `.hero` force gallery height to fit

But because the code has been cobbled together, I guess I don't fully understand how to optimise things - I also find the ternary if/else kind of confusing as well:

```
$(function() {

  // set gallery height on load
  galleryHeight();


  // navigation and item fade
  $('div.gallery-nav a').click(function () {

    var buttonIsPrev = $(this).hasClass('gallery-nav-prev') ? 'prev' : 'next';
        gallery = $(this).closest('.gallery');
        currentItem = gallery.find('.gallery-item.active');
        next = currentItem[buttonIsPrev]().length > 0 ? currentItem[buttonIsPrev]() : gallery.find('.gallery-item').filter (
          buttonIsPrev == 'prev' ? ':last' : ':first'
        );

    next.fadeIn(300, function() {
      currentItem.hide().removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active')
    });

    return false;
  });


  // zoom button
  $('.gallery-zoom').click(function () {

    var gallery = $(this).closest('.gallery'),
        galleryItem = gallery.find('.gallery-item')

    gallery.toggleClass('gallery-zoomed');

    if (gallery.hasClass('gallery-zoomed')) {
      gallery.add(galleryItem).height('100%');
    } else {
      gallery.add(galleryItem).height('auto');
      galleryHeight();
    }

    return false;
  });


  function galleryHeight(){
    $('.gallery, .gallery-item').each(function(){
      var parentHeight = $(this).parents('.hero').height();
      $(this).height(parentHeight);
    });
  }
});
```

Can anyone see why the slide transitions start getting a bit sluggish? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay you're experiencing is the 300-ms duration specified for `next.fadeIn`. The reason that you don't notice it until you've clicked a few times is that all the `div.gallery-item` elements are initially non-hidden (i.e. lack `display: none` in their styles), and hence the callback for `.fadeIn` executes without a 300-ms delay (the callback is delayed only if the element needs to be faded-in, which it doesn't if it's already non-hidden). Once you've navigated off of one of the `div.gallery-item`s, though, it gets hidden (`currentItem.hide()`), which means that the `.fadeIn` callback will be delayed when you next navigate back to it.

Reduce or eliminate the duration in `next.fadeIn` to make this work faster.